# Ngxs state.result display data objects in angular html

Tags: angular, typescript

So i have this Object that i wan to display **cartItem quantity products name,price**

```
{
    "cart": {
        "id": 6,
        "grandTotal": 1000,
        "cartItem": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "quantity": 1,
                "totalPrice": 55.5,
                "product": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Vans Shoes",
                    "price": 55.5
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "quantity": 1,
                "totalPrice": 111,
                "product": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Nike Shoes",
                    "price": 55.5
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "quantity": 1,
                "totalPrice": 55.5,
                "product": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Volcom T-shirt",
                    "price": 55.5
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the interface

```
export interface Cart {
  id:number;
  grandTotal:number;
  cartItem:CartItem;
  user:User;
}
```

The problem with ngfor is that i dont get any context in my screen even not an error.
And some time undefined property of item error.
With ngif i can display only cart properties as id grand total.
Do i need to make loop through this object to display data??
what is the proper way to display them?? Any idea?
PS this data is the result of ngxs state.

Comment: You interface defines a singular `CartItem` where your data is a List/Array

Comment: core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. I tried it that and i gave me this error

Comment: Could you post your *ngFor HTML? Can't say without the HTML why it thinks you are pointing to an object that is not an iterable.